# Insert aggregated records in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a table with three fields: `Date`, `ID1`, and `ID2` which looks like:

```
Date          ID1     ID2
-------------------------    
20130101      10      20 
20130101      30      40
20130102       5      10
20130102       7      12
20130102       8      20
```

I want to have one row per each Date/ID. How can I create a table based on the table above, in which there are only two columns: `Date` and `ID`?

`ID` includes all `ID1` and `ID2`s from the previous table:

```
Date          ID 
----------------- 
20130101      10
20130101      20        
20130101      30
20130101      40
20130102       5
20130102      10
20130102       7
20130102      12
20130102       8
20130102      20
```

Comment: Note that your current table implies some sort of relationship between `id1` and `id2` - transforming them will remove this information, is that problematic?  Also, `date` is a terrible name for a column - what is it a date for/of/about?

Comment: It is not a problem to remove the relationship between ID1 and ID2 in the new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Union. This will not show any possible duplicate Date, ID combinations. If you do want this, use UNION ALL.

```
SELECT Date, ID1 AS ID FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT Date, ID2 FROM MyTable
```

Comment: If there is no need to get rid of duplicates upon forming a result set, `union all` set operator will be a better fit. Also using `union all` will allow you to get the job more quickly, because there is no need to do an extra work of removing duplicates. As another option, you may consider using `unpivot` operator(Oracle 11g and up) [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20441)